# How to abort App Engine pipelines gracefully?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, appengine-pipeline

### Problem

I have a chain of pipelines:

```
class PipelineA(base_handler.PipelineBase):
  def run(self, *args):
    # do something

class PipelineB(base_handler.PipelineBase):
  def run(self, *args):
    # do something


class EntryPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
  def run(self):

    if some_condition():
      self.abort("Condition failed. Pipeline aborted!")

    yield PipelineA()

    mr_output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
      # mapreduce configs here
      # ...
    )

    yield PipelineB(mr_output)

p = EntryPipeline()
p.start()
```

In `EntryPipeline`, I am testing some conditions before starting `PipelineA`, `MapreducePipeline` and `PipelineB`. If the condition fail, I want to abort `EntryPipeline` and all subsequent pipelines.

### Questions

1. What is a graceful pipeline abortion? Is `self.abort()` the correct way to do it or do I need `sys.exit()`?
2. What if I want to do the abortion inside `PipelineA`? e.g. `PipelineA` kicks off successfully, but prevent subsequent pipelines(`MapreducePipeline` and `PipelineB`) from starting.

---

### Edit:

I ended up moving the condition statement outside of `EntryPipeline`, so start the whole thing only if the condition is true.  Otherwise I think Nick's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the docs currently say "***TODO: Talk about explicit abort and retry***"

we'll have to read the source:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/blob/master/python/src/pipeline/pipeline.py#L703

```
  def abort(self, abort_message=''):
    """Mark the entire pipeline up to the root as aborted.
    Note this should only be called from *outside* the context of a running
    pipeline. Synchronous and generator pipelines should raise the 'Abort'
    exception to cause this behavior during execution.

    Args:
      abort_message: Optional message explaining why the abort happened.

    Returns:
      True if the abort signal was sent successfully; False if the pipeline
      could not be aborted for any reason.
    """
```

So if you have a handle to **some_pipeline** that *isn't* **self**, you can call **some_pipeline.abort()**... but if you want to abort yourself you need to **raise Abort()** ... and that will bubble up to the top and kill the whole tree